# Show plain text in password text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show plain text in password text area by clicking a check box. I have it working for one of the text box's, but I would like to get it to work with both this is the code that I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

<title>None</title>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
//Place this plugin snippet into another file in your applicationb
(function ($) {
    $.toggleShowPassword = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            field: "#password",
            control: "#toggle_show_password",
        }, options);

        var control = $(settings.control);
        var field = $(settings.field)

        control.bind('click', function () {
            if (control.is(':checked')) {
                field.attr('type', 'text');
            } else {
                field.attr('type', 'password');
            }
        })
    };
}(jQuery));

//Here how to call above plugin from everywhere in your application document body
$.toggleShowPassword({
    field: '#password1',
    field: '#password2',
    control: '#checkbox1'
});
});//]]> 

</script>

</head>    
<body>

Password: <input type="password" id="password" value="a" />

Password 2: <input type="password" id="password2" value="a" />

<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />Show password

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript objects cannot have two keys with the same name (field and field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLg8hg2a/)

First of all if you define an object with multiple times the same property name it will only assign it the last value given. So

```
$.toggleShowPassword({
    field: '#password1, #password2',
    control: '#checkbox1'
});
```

will fix it.

Secondly, your first passwordbox's id is "password" without the 1.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overwriting the `field` option (defining it twice), put both input IDs in it:

```
$.toggleShowPassword({
    field: '#password, #password2',
    control: '#checkbox1'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a class to the input fields like so:

```
Password: <input type="password" class="togglepassfield" id="password" value="a" />
Password 2: <input type="password" class="togglepassfield" id="password2" value="a" />
```

And then using the class name:

```
$.toggleShowPassword({
   field: '.togglepassfield',
   control: '#checkbox1'
});
```